# Relate model to python object

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have some code in which I have defined some Python models.

For example:

```
class Store(object):
    '''
    The store object... Should it be a Django model?
    '''

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.name = kwargs['name']
        self.id = kwargs['id']

    def __str__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.name


kittenstore = Store(name='kittenstore', id=1)
dogstore = Store(name='dogstore', id=2)

stores_list = [kittenstore, dogstore]

class Stores(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.stores = stores_list

    def get_choices(self):
        store_choices = ()
        for store in self.stores: 
            store_choices+= ((store.id, store.name),)
        return store_choices
```

I'd like to refer to those stores from another Django model.

I could use a models.Integerfield with choices=get_choices(), but when I filter in a related models, then I always get the id back and I need to find the correlating store if I want to use it in my code.

Is there not a (python) trick to get back the Store object instead of the id?

Maybe with a custom Field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Referring to these stores from another model" implies that there should be some kind of (logical) *relationship* between those models. This is usually depicted by connecting the models with a foreign key.

In other words, you can try something like this:

```
from django.db import models

class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    id = models.CharField(max_length=5)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Store is named: %s' % self.name

class Stores(models.Model):
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Stores is at %s store" % (self.store)
```

Create your store and save it:

```
kittenstore = Store(name='kittenstore', id='1')
kittenstore.save()
```

Instantiate your Stores:

```
st = Stores(id=None, store=kittenstore)
st.save()
```

And now you can access your store object like this:

```
st.kittenstore
```

The relationship I used in this example is a *Many-to-one relationship*. You should decide on the relationship that best suits your needs by taking a look at the Django documentation regarding model [relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/).

***EDIT***If you mean associate them via the model's attributes then you can assign a model attribute to an instance of a class. For a related example on the matter, take a look at [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-model-fields/).

Comment: I have made many ForeignKey relationships to connect a model to another model before, but now I want to connect a model to a Python object instead. Is this possible, or should I just create another model with a fixture instead?

Comment: How do you mean "connect a model to a Python object"? Do you mean associate them via the model's attributes? If that's the case, then yes you can assign a model attribute to an instance of a class. For a related example on the matter, take a look at [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-model-fields/).

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted! Could add the link to your answer, then I will accept it. Thank you!

Comment: Done. Happy that I've helped!